# An advanced algebra question

Tags: ring-theory, field-theory

How can I show that $\Bbb{R}(x)$ (the quotient field of $\Bbb{R}[x]$) is not a real closed field ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: If $\pm x$ had a square root, then there should exist polynomials $p(x), q(x)$ such that
$$
\pm x=\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)^2
$$
for one choice of the sign. Clear the denominator from the above equation, and study the degrees of both sides.

Comment: I think that you can more or less take your pick from [the list of equivalent conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_closed_field#Definitions), and show that $\mathbb{R}(x)$ does not have that property.

Comment: Your argument shows that no field of the form $F(x)$ ($F$ a field) is real closed. Right ?!

Comment: Correct! ${}{}$